# Receber valores (popup) na página pai

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Em uma outra pergunta, conseguiram me ajudar sobre armazenar os valores de alguns `input` de um popup, para passar para a página pai.

**Resumo.jsp** (pág pai)

```
<input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Palavras" />
<div id="idPai"></div>

function test(){
  window.showModalDialog('saida.jsp',null,'status:off;center:yes;scroll:no;');
}
```

No popup, há uma função, `addCampos()`, para que o usuário crie vários campos `input`.

**saida.jsp** (popup)

```
<div id="campoPai"></div>
<input type="text" id='ctxt' name="campo[]" class="form-control">   
<input type="button" value="Adicionar campos" onclick="addCampos()">
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="enviaDados();">Envia Dados</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var qtdeCampos = 0;
  function addCampos() {
    var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
    var objFilho = document.createElement("div");//Criando o elemento DIV;
    objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);//Definindo atributos ao objFilho
    objPai.appendChild(objFilho);//Inserindo o elemento no pai
    //Escrevendo algo no filho recém-criado:
    document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='ctxt"+qtdeCampos+"' name='campo[]'>\n\<input type='button' onclick='removerCampo("+qtdeCampos+")' value='Apagar campo'>";
    qtdeCampos++;
  }
  function removerCampo(id) {
    var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
    var objFilho = document.getElementById("filho"+id);
    //Removendo o DIV com id específico do nó-pai:
    var removido = objPai.removeChild(objFilho);
  }
</script>
```

No método abaixo, é a parte principal da outra pergunta, é onde é passado os valores (um array) para a página pai.

```
<script language="javascript">
  function enviaDados(){
    $("#idPai").html(""); // Aqui irá resetar o conteudo da div.
    $('input[id^="ctxt"]').each(function(){
    $("#idPai").append("<p><b> Valor do Imput: "+$(this).val()+"</b></p>");
    });
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```

**Atualização**

O meu problema é que não sei como usar (pegar) esse valor na página pai.
O que preciso é: o usuário vai digitar várias palavras no popup, quando fechar o popup, as palavras digitadas serão comparadas com um array java, e assim somente as palavras digitadas que estiverem contidas nesse array serão mostradas na tela.

Comment: Amiguinho, você pode pegar os valores a partir do `each` colocando o `$(this).val()` em um array no objeto `window` usando a função `Array.push()`.

Comment: vc pode dar um exemplo? Não tenho costume com programação HTML/JavaScript

Comment: @Pacíficão Opa, tu precisa pegar os valores dos inputs e jogar para o jsp pai ( aqui se entende como o proprio html já renderizado), ou para o java?

Comment: @Matheus preciso jogar para o JSP pai. Lá vou usa-lo em uma função java.

Comment: @Pacíficão Acho que está um pouco confuso, no jsp se entende como o html com suas funções JavaScript, se tu quer jogar para o java, pq não usa um Form normal?

Comment: @Matheus Em resumo, oq eu preciso é: Receber essas palavras digitadas no popup e comparar com um vetor que está em java. Só mostrarei na pág, as palavras que foram digitadas e estiverem no vetor em java. Ficou menos confuso agora?

Comment: @Pacíficão Agora entendi o que você precisa. Porém terá que editar a pergunta, anexando tal problema para que possam te auxiliar.

Comment: @Matheus existe alguma forma de comprar em tempo-real os valores do `each` com os do `array java`?

Comment: @devgaspa Sim, partindo do principio que o programador pegou a lista do java e passou para um array no JS. Depois apenas se compara os valores do each com o array vindo do java.

Comment: @Matheus então, suponhamos que exista uma `array JS` com os valores a partir do java, apenas usando `if(arrayJsComValoresDoJava.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1)` eu consigo verificar a existência do valor.

Comment: @devgaspa A princípio sim, e isso resolveria o problema da pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos lá, para pegar os dados você usa a mesma função(`$(this).val()`), dentro do `each`, que esta atribuindo os valores na `div#idPai` do HTML.

Para armazenar esses valores em um `array` você declara uma variável antes da função `enviaDados`. Dentro do `each`, a cada execução, você adiciona no `array` o valor utilizando a função [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Veja como fica no código:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var arrayDados = []; // declaração do array no escopo global.
  function enviaDados(){
    $("#idPai").html(""); // Aqui irá resetar o conteudo da div.
    $('input[id^="ctxt"]').each(function(){
      arrayDados.push($(this).val()); // adiciona o valor no array.
      $("#idPai").append("<p><b> Valor do Imput: "+$(this).val()+"</b></p>");
    });
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```

Esta implementação é para guardar os valores que vieram do modal em um `array` no escopo global do JavaScript, sendo possível acessar da pagina *pai*.

**@Edit**

Pressupondo que você tenha criado um `array` no JS com os valores do JAVA, como nosso amigo @Matheus disse nos comentários, sendo este array de escopo global. Para verificar a existência dos valores você pode utilizar a função [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) para validar.

***Obs:*** Vamos supor que você criou o `array` `var ArrayJScomValoresDoJava = [x,p,t,o]` com os valores do `array` do JAVA.

Veja como fica no código:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function enviaDados(){
    $("#idPai").html(""); // Aqui irá resetar o conteudo da div.
    $('input[id^="ctxt"]').each(function(){
      if(ArrayJScomValoresDoJava.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1) {
        $("#idPai").append("<p><b> Valor do Imput: "+$(this).val()+"</b></p>");
      };
    });
    window.close();
  };
</script>
```

Esta implementação irá adicionar à `div#idPai` apenas quando o valor passado pelo modal existir no `array`, leia sobre `indexOf` se houver dúvidas.

Comment: Como eu acesso esse vetor na página pai?

Comment: @Pacíficão através da variável `arrayDados`. Porem pela discussão nos comentários, talvez, este exemplo não seja viável para seu problema.